# unexpected output sql server using count

Tags: sql-server

I am using sql-server 2012

The query is :

```
CREATE TABLE TEST ( NAME VARCHAR(20) );
INSERT TEST
        ( NAME
        )
        SELECT NULL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'James'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'JAMES'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'Eric';

SELECT NAME
      , COUNT(NAME) AS T1
      , COUNT(COALESCE(NULL, '')) T2
      , COUNT(ISNULL(NAME, NULL)) T3
      , COUNT(DISTINCT ( Name )) T4
      , COUNT(DISTINCT ( COALESCE(NULL, '') )) T5
      , @@ROWCOUNT T6
    FROM TEST
    GROUP BY Name;
DROP TABLE TEST;
```

In the result set ther is no 'JAMES' ? (caps)

please tell how this was excluded

expected was `Null,james,JAMES,eric`

Answer (score 3):

You need to change your `Name` column collation to `Latin1_General_CS_AS` which is `case sensitive`

```
SELECT NAME COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS,
       Count(NAME)                            AS T1,
       Count(COALESCE(NULL, ''))              T2,
       Count(Isnull(NAME, NULL))              T3,
       Count(DISTINCT ( Name ))               T4,
       Count(DISTINCT ( COALESCE(NULL, '') )) T5,
       @@ROWCOUNT                             T6
FROM   TEST
GROUP  BY Name COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS;
```

Comment: `COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS;` what it does to the query?

Comment: @HareRamaHareKrishna your database collation is case insensitive which will consider `JAMES`, `James` and `james` as same. `COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS` will make the query to be case sensitive

Answer (score 2):

Use a sensitive case collation like `COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS`.

```
CREATE TABLE TEST ( NAME VARCHAR(20) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS );
```

Comment: `COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS; what it does to the query? `

Comment: @HareRamaHareKrishna read about [collate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(COLLATE_TSQL);k(SQL11.SWB.TSQLRESULTS.F1);k(SQL11.SWB.TSQLQUERY.F1);k(MISCELLANEOUSFILESPROJECT);k(DevLang-TSQL)&rd=true), it is much better than anyone trying to explain it in a comment

Answer (score 1):

The other people who commented here are correct.

It would be easier for you to understand their meaning if you googled for collation and case sensitivity, but in layman's terms it's like this:

Collation is a little like encoding; It determines how the characters in string columns are interpreted, ordered and compared to one another. Case insensitive means that UPPERCASE / lowercase are considered exactly the same, so for instance 'JAMES', 'james', 'JaMeS' etc would be no different to SQL Server. So when your database has a case-insensitive collation and you then create a table with a column without defining the collation, that column will inherit the default collation used by the database, which is how we arrived here.

You can manually alter a column collation, or define it during a query, but bear in mind that whenever you compare two different columns, you need to assign both of them to use the same collation, or you will get an error. That's why it's good practice to pretty much use the same collation throughout the database barring special query-specific circumstances.

To your question regarding what **Latin1_General_CS_AS** means, it basically means "Latin1_General" alphabet, the details of which you can check online. The "CS" part means case-sensitive, if it were case-insensitive you would see "CI" instead. The "AS" means accent-sensitivity, and "AI" would mean accent-insensitivity. Basically, whether 'Á' is considered to be equal to 'A', or not.

You can read a lot more about it from the source, [here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143726.aspx)